# How could I see that a strongly monotonically monolithic space $X$ is first countable?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a subset of $X$. A family $\mathcal B$ of subsets of $X$
is called an an external base of $A$ in $X$ if all elements of
$\mathcal B$ are open in $X$ and for any $x\in A$ and any open set
$U$ in $X$ with $x\in U$, there exists some $B\in \mathcal B$ such
that $x\in B \subset U$.

We say that a space $X$ is strongly
monotonically monolithic if for each $A \subset X$ we can assign an
external base $\mathcal{O}(A)$
to the set $\overline{A}$ satisfying the following conditions:

a) $\left| \mathcal{O}(A) \right| \le \max\{|A|,\omega\}$;

b) if $A \subset B $, then $\mathcal{O}(A) \subset
\mathcal{O}(B)$;

c) if $\alpha$ is an ordinal and we have a family $\{A_\beta: \beta
< \alpha \}$ of subsets of $X$ such that $\beta < \beta' $ implies
$A_{\beta} \subset A_{\beta'}$, then $\mathcal{O}(\bigcup_{\beta <
\alpha} A_\beta) = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \mathcal{O}(A_\beta)$.

**How could I see that a strongly
monotonically monolithic space $X$ is first countable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $X$ is $T_1$. Fix a point $p\in X$, and let $A=\{p\}$. Let $\mathcal{O}(A)$ be the promised external base for $\operatorname{cl}A=A$. Then $|\mathcal{O}(A)|=\omega$, and for each open nbhd $U$ of $p$ in $X$ we have a $B\in\mathcal{O}(A)$ such that $p\in B\subseteq U$. But that just means that $\mathcal{O}(A)$ is a local base at $p$, so $\chi(p,X)=\omega$. And $p$ was arbitrary, so $\chi(X)=\omega$.